# ElasticSearch in Docker dies silently and restarts, but why?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am monitoring a docker that runs ElasticSearch 6.2.3

Every day it dies, and I have not been able to figure out why...

I think it is memory, but where can I find proof of that ?

Running top on the host (Linux) I get
Virtual Mem = 53 Gig
Res = 26.7 
right now ! that is...

docker docker inspect gives me this

```
  "Memory": 34225520640,

        "CpusetMems": "",

        "KernelMemory": 0,

        "MemoryReservation": 0,

        "MemorySwap": 34225520640,

        "MemorySwappiness": null,

                "Name": "memlock",
```

The JVM params are

```
/usr/bin/java

-Xms1g

-Xmx1g

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75

-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly

-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

-Xss1m

-Djava.awt.headless=true

-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

-Djna.nosys=true

-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

-Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true

-Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true

-Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0

-Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false

-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true

-Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/elasticsearch/tmp

-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

-XX:+PrintGCDetails

-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps

-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution

-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime

-Xloggc:logs/gc.log

-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation

-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32

-XX:GCLogFileSize=64m

-Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/

-Xms26112m

-Xmx26112m

-Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch

-Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config

-cp

/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*

org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
```

and here is the log

```
[2019-01-30T07:14:01,278] [app-mesos-orders_api-2019.01.30/6l7Ga1I5T3qhLKYmWjQpRA] update_mapping [doc]
[2019-01-30T07:25:53,489] initializing ...
[2019-01-30T07:25:53,581] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/mapper/vg_tobias-lv_tobias)]], net usable_space [126.8gb], net total_space [199.8gb], types [xfs]
[2019-01-30T07:25:53,581] heap size [25.4gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2019-01-30T07:26:12,390], node ID [-sJqW_h1TKy9c_Ka08In0A]
[2019-01-30T07:26:12,391] version[6.2.3], pid[1], build[c59ff00/2018-03-13T10:06:29.741383Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_151/25.151-b12]
[2019-01-30T07:26:12,391] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/elasticsearch/tmp, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -Xloggc:logs/gc.log, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32, -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms26112m, -Xmx26112m, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,008] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,008] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,008] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,008] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,008] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,009] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,009] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,009] loaded module [parent-join]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,009] loaded module [percolator]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,009] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,009] loaded module [reindex]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,009] loaded module [repository-url]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,009] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,009] loaded module [tribe]
[2019-01-30T07:26:13,009] no plugins loaded
[2019-01-30T07:26:19,947] using discovery type [zen]
[2019-01-30T07:26:20,444] initialized
[2019-01-30T07:26:20,444] starting ...
[2019-01-30T07:26:20,600] publish_address {172.16.44.8:9300}, bound_addresses {172.17.0.14:9300}
[2019-01-30T07:26:21,507] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2019-01-30T07:26:24,855] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined), reason: new_master {elasticsearch-1}{-sJqW_h1TKy9c_Ka08In0A}{iGTgehBjQ3yPRm9nlTLbYw}{172.16.44.8}{172.16.44.8:9300}{rack=rack1}
[2019-01-30T07:26:24,861] new_master {elasticsearch-1}{-sJqW_h1TKy9c_Ka08In0A}{iGTgehBjQ3yPRm9nlTLbYw}{172.16.44.8}{172.16.44.8:9300}{rack=rack1}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {elasticsearch-1}{-sJqW_h1TKy9c_Ka08In0A}{iGTgehBjQ3yPRm9nlTLbYw}{172.16.44.8}{172.16.44.8:9300}{rack=rack1} committed version [1] source [zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)]])
[2019-01-30T07:26:24,881] publish_address {172.16.44.8:9200}, bound_addresses {172.17.0.14:9200}
[2019-01-30T07:26:24,881] started
[2019-01-30T07:26:37,033] recovered [1535] indices into cluster_state
```

I am thinking that the Docker container runs out of memory and dies silently

How can I prove this ? and what can I do to solve this ?

Comment: containers binded to each other? 
try to
network.bind_host:

Comment: at the moment, there is only ONE container running, so a one-node Elastic cluster in other words

Comment: I now know half the story of why it was killed
The Linux host kills a process when the host is about to run out of memory. oom-killer.

Comment: I now know half the story of why it was killed...
The Linux host kills a process when the host is about to run out of memory
It has a oom-killer, that looks at the ooo-score that each process receives. The score can be found; cat /proc/10292/oom_score
Now since my ElasticSearch Docker had tons of memory, it's oom-score went through the roof, 383, and hence it was easy for the Linux OS oom-killer process to select which process to kill.
BUT how do I solve this problem, how do I tell Elastic that it should honor the max memory as specified for the Docker Container.